# sencha touch :: substr() on itemTpl of LIST

Tags: javascript, list, sencha-touch, itemtemplate, substr

how could I shorten long names inside a list object in sencha touch when my template ist build like

```
itemTpl: '{firstName} {lastName}',
```

thnx!

EDIT: thanx for your tries, buddies! my problem is that I use

```
plugins: [new app.plugins.editableList()], // by WhiteFox AS
```

which seems to make the trouble. while without plugin the simple

```
{ 
  xtype: 'list',
  ...
  itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div>{[this.shortenName(values)]}</div>',
    '</tpl>',
    {
        shortenName: function(values) {
            return values.firstName.substr(0, 5);
        }
    }
),
...}
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed the javascript in the template. If you have some function "truncate", you can just do

```
{[truncate(values.firstName,5) + " " + truncate(values.lastName,5)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store the value you would like in the data store? If it's only the last initial you want, store that in your data store and call it:

```
itemTpl: '{firstName} {lastInitial}',
```

Comment: in the store I need the full name. in the list it only needs to show a shortened like theString.substr(0,16) + '...'

Comment: could you add last initial to the model as a calculated field based on the last name field? That way you could have both the last name and last initial on the model.